# lightweight http server C++

Tags: c++, http, webserver

I need to build a lightweight http server for my application
basically it's a server which listen to a port and outputs a status information on requests
no high load, https,  other functionality is required
is there any C++ library which would help me to build an http server

Comment: @user490710 have look at boost..If windows, why not WinHTTP?

Comment: There is also pion the network library http://prog-xp.blogspot.fr/2011/01/creating-simple-web-server-with-pion.html

Comment: Poco (http://pocoproject.org) can be an option. It has ready-made HTTP server.

Comment: Closed as not constructive? Why not remove it also, so that those of us who where looking for *exactly* this can meet someplace more, ehm, *constructive* ?

Comment: I can't believe that they closed this question. The post has 11 votes and many useful answers. Can any of the moderators at least elaborate on why it was closed?

Comment: Closed as "non constructive" is really a joke.

Comment: For future reference, look also into [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)

Answer (score 22):

Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/. I think it's separated in a library that does exactly what you want. It's written in C, though.

Comment: +1 My team uses mongoose for lightweight services... it's ~5200 lines of C, three source files, one man page and a hundred line Makefile.  main.c servers as a good illustration of how to call mg_start() to start the server in a background thread....

Comment: I'd like to take the opportunity to ask whether mongoose has known limitations for non-lightweight services. If I carefully craft the website, can it be used as a replacement for PHP in terms of performance, or will mongoose lag me behind it if I don't tweak its source-code?

Comment: you've lost me - PHP is a language used for dynamic generation of content, and easily callable by a HTTP daemon (web server, e.g. mongoose), but it's not a HTTP daemon itself.  I don't see how mongoose can replace PHP as it's a completely separate beast.  Still, you might wonder if Apache+PHP can outperform mongoose+PHP... I don't know - I've never even tried using PHP with mongoose.  We serve really simple stuff: static HTML and style sheets.

Comment: Ah, well. The pragmatism of the hells.. I mean it comparatively. Will Apache+PHP generally outperform mongoose+MyOwnC++CodeRenderingThePages? I'm not comparing daemons here, but the pair daemon-website engine. Considering Apache certainly does a better job at handling requests, will the C++ code with mongoose still win a PHP website just because PHP is interpreted and etc, or will mongoose be the cause to really lag me behind? That's what I meant to ask. Sorry if I shortened a bit too much..

Comment: And I meant pedanticism, not pragmatism. Just thought I should correct that as well :)

Comment: The author just changed the license from MIT to GPL. Now that's great news.

Answer (score 9):

Mongoose has now a C++ wrapper - see:

http://code.google.com/r/vpiotr-mongoose-cpp/

Answer (score 5):

how about these [boost.asio examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html), you got 5 choices as of version 1.44. or you may try [cpp-netlib](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/CppSoup/~3/W1UzCGynF2s/), which is built on boost.asio and meant to be included in [boost](http://www.boost.org).

Answer (score 4):

Here is another light weight server which can be used along c++ .

http://sourceforge.net/projects/miniweb/
see , what features match your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

There is [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/manual/libmicrohttpd.html). I had to write quite some glue code to make it fit my purpose, though; but I never regretted.

Comment: May I ask why it needed glue? It looks perfect.

Comment: @n2liquid: Although it has some options for using it with another event loop, this was not sufficient for my case (a GUI app, i.e. Glib/Gtk(mm)). Also the API is lower level than serving e.g. a complete local directory.

Comment: Ah, I see. I personally hate libraries stealing the main loop..

Answer (score 3):

If you want any interactivity, consider using [wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt).

Answer (score 0):

Everything is there (c++ standard)... sockets, read/write if TCP, and other functions for UDP (if you will use it), etc... There's nothing else you'll need but networking functions, the rest is up to file managing (reading html files and such) and threading if you wanna go further.

I REALLY advice you to read this guide:

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

It's free and it explains everything you need to implement that little web server.

I'm supposing this is an assignment, i didn't get this on my networking classes, but some friends did, and it's pretty easy and fun to do if you have some little c++ knowledge.

Comment: But if you want it really RFC compliant -- instead of just working with common browsers -- its not exactly trivial, either.

Comment: @smilingthax: i know, that's why I assumed it was a college assignment. You can't really code a RFC compliant web server in 1 or 2 weeks, which is the normal deadline, while having to study other stuff. If it is indeed an assignment, it probably wants a simple threaded (or not, mine was threaded) web server, which can handle basically GET, POST and some other simple HTML stuff, and manage some html files. If it isn't an assignment.. why on earth would someone want to code their own web server with so many light and secure implementations out there?

Comment: "Everything is there (c++ standard)... sockets, read/write if TCP, and other functions for UDP (if you will use it), etc.". Is there anything to do with HTTP, like a header parser?

Comment: "I'm supposing this is an assignment". Well, I have a similar problem and it is not an assignment! :-)